# Why is the TitleBar title gone after adding acrylic effect?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I used the following code in MainPage.xaml.cs to add acrylic effect on the TitleBar

```
public void AcrylicTitleBar()
    {
        CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
        var title = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        title.TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        title.TitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        title.TitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = (Color)Resources["SystemBaseHighColor"];
    }
```

but I don't know why the TitleBar title is gone.

[image: No TitleBar title]

If I remove the above code the TitleBar title comes back. can someone please help me?

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is **not** applying any "Acrylic" effect to your app Title bar . 
It is simply setting the button background color to "Transparent" which is no where close to the acrylic.

In order to have an acrylic title bar you need to do the following :

In your `MainPage.xaml.cs` , add code for hiding the default title bar and update its layout so that it still works like the default toolbar :

```
public MainPage()
{
    // Hide default title bar.
    var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    UpdateTitleBarLayout(coreTitleBar);
}

private void UpdateTitleBarLayout(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar)
{
    // Get the size of the caption controls area and back button 
    // (returned in logical pixels), and move your content around as necessary.
    LeftPaddingColumn.Width = new GridLength(coreTitleBar.SystemOverlayLeftInset);
    RightPaddingColumn.Width = new GridLength(coreTitleBar.SystemOverlayRightInset);
    TitleBarButton.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, coreTitleBar.SystemOverlayRightInset, 0);

    // Update title bar control size as needed to account for system size changes.
    AppTitleBar.Height = coreTitleBar.Height;
}

private void CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
{
    UpdateTitleBarLayout(sender);
}
```

Next , in your `MainPage.xaml` add `AcrylicBrush` as the *main* or *parent* grid background (Note : that this grid should wrap all the contents in the page ):

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Background>
    <AcrylicBrush BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" 
                  TintColor="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}" 
                  FallbackColor="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}" 
                  TintOpacity="0.5">
     </AcrylicBrush>
  </Grid.Background>
 </Grid>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fwiw, this is the actual system resources for this: `<AcrylicBrush x:Key="SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="{StaticResource SystemChromeAltHighColor}" TintOpacity="0.8" FallbackColor="{StaticResource SystemChromeMediumColor}" />`